# How can I selectively copy details from a file and paste them into a new file?

Tags: c#, json, string, mongodb, find

I am at a stump here, kinda don't know where to start looking...
Here is an example of my data stored in a txt file:

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult]
{ "_id" : 3000020, "Payload" : { "category_id" : "/1/1/", "Data" : { "category_id" : "/1/1/2/", "Temperature" : 24.100000000000001, "VDD" : 3568, "Humidity" : 31 }, "Raw Data" : { "category_id" : "/1/1/3/", "payload_hex" : "0100f1021f070df0" }, "Sensitive" : { "category_id" : "/1/1/1/" } }, "DeviceID" : 6, "Time" : 1525069485 }
{ "_id" : 3000032, "Payload" : { "category_id" : "/1/1/", "Data" : { "category_id" : "/1/1/2/", "Humidity" : 32, "Temperature" : 22.100000000000001, "VDD" : 3639, "CO2" : 510 }, "Raw Data" : { "category_id" : "/1/1/3/", "payload_hex" : "0100dd02200601fe070e37" }, "Sensitive" : { "category_id" : "/1/1/1/" } }, "DeviceID" : 18, "Time" : 1525069658 }
{ "_id" : 3000041, "Payload" : { "category_id" : "/1/1/", "Data" : { "category_id" : "/1/1/2/", "Temperature" : 24.100000000000001, "VDD" : 3568, "Humidity" : 31 }, "Raw Data" : { "category_id" : "/1/1/3/", "payload_hex" : "0100f1021f070df0" }, "Sensitive" : { "category_id" : "/1/1/1/" } }, "DeviceID" : 6, "Time" : 1525069785 }
```

What I am looking for is to display specific parts of data, Temperature for example, line by line in another txt file. Kinda Like this:

```
24.100000000000001
22.100000000000001
24.100000000000001
```

I am working with c# in my project...

Comment: Looks like, you're going to use JSON here. Take a look at Newtonsoft.Json library.

Comment: I am working with c# in my unity project...

Comment: Do you have a code of class, behind this data? Or you only have the strings?

Comment: If you don't take a look at this : https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryingLINQtoJSON.htm

Btw, if you dont know how to import .net dlls into Unity project, look at the Unity's Plugins folder https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Plugins.html

Comment: @Kamiky, I just have these strings. I get them from a remote DB...

Comment: Your string is in JSON format. So you should study a little bit of it and how to serialize JSON strings to C# objects. @Kamiky shared a good link to start.

Comment: What DB are you using in this project?

Comment: @Lutti Coelho, MongoDB

Comment: Can you access this db from your app? Or you only has access to the text file?

Comment: @LuttiCoelho I can access the DB, yes, but the way things are already made txt files is the way to go. I basically brute force, does not need to be coded pretty, just functional. I will post a reply here with code if I come up with something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you say you don't mind a "brute force" solution, we are just going to parse the temperature substring out of the source JSON string without deserializing it or doing anything fancy:

```
public string GetTemperature(string inputJson)
{
    string temperature = null;

    string[] dataPairs = inputJson.Split(',');

    foreach (string dataPair in dataPairs)
    {
        if (dataPair.Contains("Temperature"))
        {
            string[] temperatureData = dataPair.Split(':');
            temperature = temperatureData[1].Trim();
            break;
        }
    }

    return temperature;
}
```

To test this, you can run it as follows:

```
string inputJson = "{ \"_id\" : 3000032, \"Payload\" : { \"category_id\" : \"/1/1/\", \"Data\" : { \"category_id\" : \"/1/1/2/\", \"Humidity\" : 32, \"Temperature\" : 22.100000000000001, \"VDD\" : 3639, \"CO2\" : 510 }, \"Raw Data\" : { \"category_id\" : \"/1/1/3/\", \"payload_hex\" : \"0100dd02200601fe070e37\" }, \"Sensitive\" : { \"category_id\" : \"/1/1/1/\" } }, \"DeviceID\" : 18, \"Time\" : 1525069658 }";
string temperature = GetTemperature(inputJson);
Console.WriteLine("Temperature: " + temperature);
```

But please note there are better (enterprise-grade) ways to solve this problem. For starters, we probably want to define the data format as a class and deserialize the JSON data into an object of that class.Then we could retrieve the temperature value from a property of the object, etc.

Comment: This looks like something that could work... Currently bashing the keyboard trying to set it up.... I am pretty bad at this as you can see

Comment: Ok, so now I am looking into implementing the method in such a way as to send the output to Console.WriteLine ...

Comment: It's really not difficult. I edited my answer and provided the test code you need.

Comment: I know that, and I am REALLY thankful... I just got thrown into a project while having not much of code experience besides sticking together tutorials... what I was building right now was a far more complicated thing... heh....

Comment: Well, if this doesn't answer your question and you aren't going mark it answered, I'd appreciate an upvote at least.

Comment: Sorry, was applying it he he.

Answer (score 1):

After @robbpriestley shared his answer I realized that, as you only need the temperature value of each line, deserialize all line as a new object just to get the temperature maybe will be too expensive to a very small job. So I'll share some ways you can do what you want and a little comparison of each way.

> Obs: The data that share looks like a file that has one valid JSON
>   object in each line. So be careful to do not try to parse all file
>   into a single object array, because your file is not valid as a JSON
>   array.

**1) Deserialize the JSON string as a C# object**.

In the example bellow I Deserialized the string to a `dynamic` type, but you probably already has a object that represents that JSON. And if you don't, you can make Visual Studio generate one by copy the JSON value and click in `Edit` > `Paste Special` > `Paste JSON As Classes`.

```
public string GetTemperatureJsonParse(string inputJson)
{
    var jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(inputJson);
    return jsonObject.Payload.Data.Temperature;
}
```

**2) Use Regular Expression to extract the value you need.**

If you don't know how to use regular expressions you can google for more information. And then you can use this site https://regexr.com/ to validate and test you own regex.

```
public string GetTemperatureByRegex(string inputJson)
{
    string pattern = "(\"Temperature\"\\s:\\s)(?<temperature>\\d+\\.?\\d*)";
    return Regex.Match(inputJson, pattern).Groups["temperature"].Value;
}
```

**3) Parse your string using JSON separetors values.**

This is the same solution that @robbpriestley shared, but using linq instead of a foreach loop.

```
public string GetTemperatureByStringParse(string inputJson)
{
    string[] dataPairs = inputJson.Split(',');
    return dataPairs.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Contains("Temperature"))?.Split(':')[1].Trim();
}
```

So, what's the difference between each solution? Performance! All solutions do exactly the same thing, but parse all data you have to new object to return only one value is very expensive. Now you have two options to get the value you need without parsing all data. What's the diference between each one?

To answer that I use a Benchmark nuget package to compare all options. This is the result:

```
|                      Method |    Gen 0 | Allocated |
|---------------------------- |---------:|-----------|
| GetTemperatureByStringParse |  1.9493  |   3.99 KB |
|       GetTemperatureByRegex |  0.9766  |   2.02 KB |
|     GetTemperatureJsonParse | 14.4653  |   29.7 KB |
```

> Gen 0     : GC Generation 0 collects per 1000 operations
>
> Allocated : Allocated memory per single operation (managed only, inclusive, 1KB = 1024B)

So I suggest you use Regular Expressions to extract the temparature value from your JSON.

I create a gist with the code I use to analyse each method. https://gist.github.com/lutticoelho/5e2438e19a0cdac88782281c45a75fe1

Comment: Very educational, thank you! Currently trying to get it working with the other answer